# how does xml define other markup language?

Tags: html, xml

I'm having a web course. And in the course the instructor said xml is a system for defining other markup language. I don't get it. How can xml define other language like html? I think html is defined by dtd.

Comment: XML and HTML are both [children of Mothra, er, SGML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html). XML is sort've the impetus of XHTML, which was aimed at building applications using HTML-"like" elements through the irrational braggarty of doctype conformance (those *rebels*). But most web developers only used it to show off their puny markup skilz to their IRC friends. Whatever.

Comment: Because of validation and schemas search for xml schema's, or even look a something like FIX (Financial Information eXchange)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML is a generic language that can be used to describe any kind of markup.  By itself it can mean anything.

When combined with a specific set of requirements and usually a schema, a more restrictive grammar can be defined that is a subset of XML and is used as a specific markup language.

XHTML, SVG are examples of subsets of XML that are defined markup languages.

Other schemas for XML define subsets of XML but don't represent markup and thus would not be properly referred to as a markup language.  For example, SOAP, WSDL, and even XSD itself define uses of XML in specific schemas but are not a form of marking up documents, and would generally not be called markup languages. (SOAP could be argued either way).

There are also markup languages that are loosely based on XML but don't adhere to the strict definitions of XML.  They are often markup languages but are not proper XML markup languages.  Examples of this would be HTML (including HTML5) and CFML.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's pretty clear now. =)